How to overcome sample/avatars is incompatible with attributes error
I am getting this error in Android studio how to resolve this
The problem is as shown

AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

I have tried many ways started again but not resolved
